# Efficient way to select row from a DataFrame based on varying list of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose, we have the following DataFrame:

```
dt = {'A': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','c'],
      'B': ['x','x','x','y','y','z','x','z','y'],
      'C': [10, 14, 15, 11, 10, 14, 14, 11, 10],
      'D': [1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dt)
```

I want to extract certain rows based on a dictionary where keys are column names and values are row values. For example:

```
d = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'x'}
d = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'y', 'C': 10}
d = {'A': 'b', 'B': 'z', 'C': 11, 'D': 4}
```

It can be done using loop (consider the last dictionary):

```
for iCol in d:
    df = df[df[iCol] == d[iCol]] 
Out[215]: 
   A  B   C  D
7  b  z  11  4
```

Since DataFrame is expected to be pretty large and it may have many columns to select on, I am looking for the efficient way to solve the problem without  using for loop to iterate the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below, Make the dict a `Series`:

```
print(df[(df[list(d)] == pd.Series(d)).all(axis=1)])
```

Output:

```
   A  B   C  D
7  b  z  11  4
```